# How to know when all async functions have completed?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to be able to call a completion block once all the asynchronous functions have completed. However, they don't all have completion blocks. This is my code:

```
func pauseStream(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    disconnectFromSession()
    model.publishers = []

    model.pauseStream() { result in

    }
}
```

`disconnectFromSession` is an asynchronous function that when completed fires a callback function `didDisconnectFromSession` in a delegate class.

Setting `model.publishers = []` posts a `Notification` to `NotificationCenter` that is received by a class which then updates a UI.

Finally `model.pauseStream()` has a completion block to let me know when it's completed.

What I need to do is once all the asynchronous parts of the code have completed, I want to call the `completion()` block of my `pauseStream` function. What's the best way to do this? Unfortunately I can't change them to all have a completion block.

Comment: Wait a sec. Do you have `pauseStream` recursively calling itself? Or is that just a typo when creating the code snippet...

Comment: @Rob yea, it looks like typo since he named closure parameter `result` and his `pauseStream` `completion` has no one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generally use dispatch groups for this sort of thing. The trick here is that if you need to wait for `disconnectFromSession` to call its completion handler, then need to have `didDisconnectFromSession` call `leave` for the dispatch group.

So create ivar for the dispatch group:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
```

Have your `pauseStream` use this `DispatchGroup` to call its completion handler when `enter` calls are offset by their corresponding `leave` calls:

```
func pauseStream(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    group.enter()
    disconnectFromSession()  // this will call `leave` in its delegate method

    model.publishers = []

    group.enter()
    model.someAsynchronousMethod() { result in
        defer { group.leave() }

        ...
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

And, your `didDisconnectFromSession`, would call that corresponding `leave`:

```
func didDisconnectFromSession(...) {
    group.leave()

    ...
}
```